# another way except voronoi diagram to separate points

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I want to decompose the space into regions around each point . voronoi diagram is the best way for this problem but actually I want to find another way to separate the points from each other in the separate regions .
thanks .

Comment: It depends what you  are trying to do, and what properties you want the regions to have ... do you just want each point to be in one region? Do the region boundaries have to be equidistant from the points?

Comment: each point must be in one region and its not important how many regions will build even it can has many blank regions .

Comment: a regular grid ? a kd-tree ? a bsp-tree ? ...... anything in particular you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you are trying to do, but [image segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) raised to my head while reading your question.

1. [best Segmentation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042445/best-segmentation-algorithm)
2. [K means algoritm](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v41/v41-112.pdf) to extract k features in a 2D array

Comment: I just want to have a lot of path between the points to find the best path from them .